# How to import a module from root directory in Python?

Tags: python

I have definitions.py in the root directory (myapp/), start.py in myapp/src/scripts/. When I import definitions from start.py I am getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'definitions'". New to python, what am I missing? Thanks!

definitions.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

start.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import definitions

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('in start = ' + definitions.ROOT_DIR)
```

I did this to make it work, is there a better solution?

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '../../')
from definitions import *
```

Comment: There's lots about this topic, see  e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder

Comment: thanks! @Demi-Lune I edited my question, know a cleaner solution?

Comment: Hi, sorry I missed your question. There is in fact a better (imho) solution, involving *packaging* : setup.py, relative import and all that related stuff. See the tutorial https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/ . If you're planning development in python and distributing your work, it is worth learning this.